# view does not change background image

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-style

I have a template in which I call a function and I have a directive element,

```
.container-wrapper{"ng-controller" => "MovieRowCtrl"}
  %i.fa.fa-info-circle{"ng-click" => "updateSelectedMovie(movie)"}

#big-box-container{"ng-if" => "rowActive"}
  %movie-details{:movie => "selectedMovie"}
```

The function is inside a directive,

```
app.directive('movieDetails', MovieDetailsDirectiveFn)
  .controller('MovieRowCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', MovieRowCtrlFn]);

function MovieDetailsDirectiveFn($animate) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      movie: '=',
    },
    templateUrl: '../assets/angular-app/templates/_movie-info.html'
  }
}

function MovieRowCtrlFn($scope, $rootScope) {
  $scope.updateSelectedMovie = function updateVisibleMovieIndexFn(movie) {
    $scope.selectedMovie = movie;
    $rootScope.$broadcast('movieRowActivated', {targetScopeId: $scope.$id});
    $scope.rowActive = true;
  }
}
```

As you can see I set my `MovieRowCtrl` as controller for the `.container-wrapper`.

So when the `updateSelectedMovie(movie)` function fires it sets the `$scope.rowActive` to true (showing the element) and it inject the `_movie-info.html` template inside the `%movie-details` element.

This works fine.

In that `_movie-info.html` template I have this,

```
.movie-background{"ng-style" => "{'background-image':'url(https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280{{movie.backdrop}})'}"}
```

Which results in,

```
<div class="movie-background" ng-style="{'background-image':'url(https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280/lXOqBOcx1t5A3YhJEIfJZOkigwH.jpg)'}" 
style="background-image: url(&quot;https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280/nbIrDhOtUpdD9HKDBRy02a8VhpV.jpg&quot;);">
```

So it creates a ng-style, and a normale style attribute for the element.

The problem is that when I fire the `updateSelectedMovie(movie)` the `ng-style` attribute gets updated with a new url, but the style attribut does not get changed.

```
<div class="movie-background" ng-style="{'background-image':'url(https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280/15PbZtjRJ4zgQA8XS0otL70piQi.jpg)'}" 
style="background-image: url(&quot;https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280/nbIrDhOtUpdD9HKDBRy02a8VhpV.jpg&quot;);">
```

Any ideas why the `ng-style` gets updated, but the other `style` does not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not need to use `{{}}` inside `ng-style`, use `+` for string concatenation while concatenating scope variable inside `ng-style` expression.

```
.movie-background{"ng-style" => 
      "{'background-image':'url(https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280' + movie.backdrop +')'}"}
```

Comment: Ah I see, you remove the single quotes around the movie.backdrop. Pfff, totally missed that. Thanks

Comment: @alucardu do accept and udvote answer, if it does helped..Thanks :)